# How to fix lable.Text as html tag with class="" and other styles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a value for bind in lable.Text 
value is this below

value I want in lable this:

```
<ul class="Class">  <li><img width="440" height="600"/></li> </ul>
```

exactly same as it is

I'm calling value in lable like this

```
string Class = "pslides"; string width = "440"; string height = "600";  
lbl.Text = "<ul class=" + Class + ">  <li><img width=" + width + " 
height=" + height + "/></li> </ul>";
```

when I check the label.Text value then I will get result this

```
<ul class=Class>  <li><img width=440 height=600/></li> </ul>
```

but I want a label.text value like this

```
 lbl.Text = "<ul class="Class">  <li><img width="width" 
    height="height"/></li> </ul>";
```

I have to do this in with code in c# please give me solution how can I get the lable.text value like I want.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just asking about having the quotes around the values? You just need to actually put the quotes in your string - you're not doing that now. You need to make sure you're escaping the quotes otherwise it won't compile.

You can add the quotes where you concatenate everything:

```
string Class = "pslides"; string width = "440"; string height = "600";  
lbl.Text = "<ul class=\"" + Class + "\">  <li><img width=\"" + width + "\" height=\"" + height + "\"/></li> </ul>";
```

or you could add them to your string values since you're already converting those numbers to strings:

```
string Class = "\"pslides\""; string width = "\"440\""; string height = "\"600\"";  
lbl.Text = "<ul class=" + Class + ">  <li><img width=" + width + " height=" + height + "/></li> </ul>";
```

Normally you'd see the former, I'd say, not the latter.

Comment: that is working but i also bind a img src and img is not getting in img tag

Comment: well, first of all, you're not binding. You're just setting values. Binding has a very specific meaning. that aside, your example code doesn't show anything about the src attribute of the img tag, so I don't know how to help you with that. If you update your original post, I'll take a look.

Comment: im doing this i want to scroll images manually using click on next button and preview for see user photo so i want to also bind images each img

Comment: I still don't see anything about the src attribute of an img tag in your post. Like I said, if you'd like to update your original post to include an example of where you're still having an issue, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just asking how to escape the quotes, use single and double quotes:

```
string cssClass = "pslides";
string width = "440";
string height = "600";

lbl.Text = "<ul class='" + cssClass + "'>" +
                    "<li>" +
                        "<img width='" + width + "' height='" + height + "'/>" +
                    "</li>" +
                "</ul>";
```

The double quotes work to enclose C# strings and the single quotes work to enclose HTML attributes. Hope this helps.

And if what you want to do is print that HTML out, do not use a **label**. You need to use a **literal**. After that, change your code to:

```
string cssClass = "pslides";
string width = "440";
string height = "600";

Literal1.Text = "<ul class='" + cssClass + "'>" +
                    "<li>" +
                        "<img width='" + width + "' height='" + height + "'/>" +
                    "</li>" +
                "</ul>";
```